# .NET Application that uses Tessnet2 fails

Tags: .net, winapi, msvcrt, tesseract

I have an app that uses [Tessnet2](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/). The application fails when I try to call its Init method.
The failure is just **awful - no exception (ANY), no any trace of error, not even "Send report" window. The app's process is just droped**.

The problematic code is:

```
Recogniser = new Tesseract();
Recogniser.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", Whitelist);
Recogniser.SetVariable("unlv_tilde_crunching", false);
Recogniser.Init(null, "eng", false); // FAILURE IS HERE
```

Couple of notes that might be helpful:

- Tessnet2 requires **Visual C++ 2008 Runtime**. Not sure if it should be msvcm90.dll, msvcm80.dll.
- The application is desktop WPF.
- Dev Environment: VS 2008 SP, .NET 3.5 SP1
- It worked before (I think I added the Web Reference to consume SOAP web-service, but I tried to remove it with no result).
- The unit tests are working perfectly with **no failures**.

From these observations it sounds like a problem with the WPF application itself.

Only one piece information I have is the Output during the debugging:

```
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'D:\...\bin\Debug\OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationProvider.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.  
The thread 0x1784 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1144 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x16a4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'D:\...\bin\Debug\OcrForm.WinApp.exe', Symbols loaded.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'OcrForm.WinApp.App.App'
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'OcrForm.WinApp.App.InitializeComponent'
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Classic\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Classic.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x374 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x13cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'D:\...\bin\Debug\OcrForm.dll', Symbols loaded.
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'D:\...\bin\Debug\Commons.dll', Symbols loaded.
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'D:\...\bin\Debug\tessnet2_32.dll', Symbols loaded.
'OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_x-ww_6f74963e\msvcm90.dll'
```

And the last piece when the app fails:

```
The program '[5384] OcrForm.WinApp.vshost.exe: Managed' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

**UPDATE:** I have checked the event log. There are no any entries with 'SideBySide' source. Only entry related to the issue is below, but unfortunately it doesn't tell me a lot:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
Event Category: None
Event ID:   5000
Date:       28/10/2009
Time:       4:07:57 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   ARGO11
Description:
EventType clr20r3, P1 ocrform.winapp.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4ae7d16c, P4 ocrform, P5 1.0.0.0, P6 4ae1333f, P7 10f, P8 1, P9 system.typeinitialization, P10 NIL.
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: We had a case like this, it was due to unhandled exceptions, FYI

Comment: What kind of exception? I do not get ANY exceptoins at all. My guess is that there is something to do with loading with C++ runtime libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

**Short answer:
The working directory of the app was changed after using [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx#Save_File_Dialog). This caused Tesseract to fail to find related files.**

Couple of thing I did for that:

1. Created a new WPF application that uses Tessnet2.
2. Started it -> it failed exactly the same way.
3. I found that I missed to add files required by tesseract.
4. Added them -> the app started to work.

Than moving to my application:
I Checked the files required by tesseract. All are in place and valid.

So there must be something else related to not being able to access the files:

1. No permissions.
2. Incorrect location.

Checked the 1st - all is fine.
Checked the 2nd - all files ARE in correct location **relatively to the application current directory**.

See the point??
BUT it turns out the files should be in the same **WORKING DIRECTORY** as application is.

**The working directory has been changed after using [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx#Save_File_Dialog)!**

If I do not use the dialog the app works.
How I could possible figure this out from all the "error information"...
Hope this will help somebody.

Comment: hhmm.. still having the same problem even though i checked point 1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the windows System event log (Start->Settings->Control Panel->Management->Event Viewer). Possibly you'll find there entries from the Windows SideBySide manager.

The last line of your output shows that a dll from SideBySide has been loaded.

I Had similar problems lately. No hint to the failure cause until we looked into the event log.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't thought about looking into the Event Log :) Will do that when I'll get to my work PC and post the results here.

Comment: Ok. I have checked the event log. Not much info is there except system.typeinitialization. I updated the question updated.